# Highlight the WFS layer on mouseover

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, style

I've set up a WFS layer in OpenLayers:

```
 var v1497_shp = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("v1497_shp", {
     strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), saveStrategy],
     protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
         version: "1.1.0",
         // loading data through localhost url path
         url: "http://localhost/geoserver/wfs",
         featureNS :  "http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite",
         maxExtent: mapextent,
         // layer name
         featureType: "v1497_db_wfs",
         // geometry column name
         geometryName: "the_geom",
         schema: "http://localhost/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?version=1.1.0&typename=cite:v1497_db_wfs"
     })
});
```

Now I want to highlight the layer when I pass over with the mouse.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

only using highlight features on hover:

> (this examples also show how eventListeners are used with
>   beforefeaturehighlighted,  featurehighlighted, featureunhighlighted)

```
 var info = function(evt) {
                OpenLayers.Console.log(evt.type, evt.feature.id);
            };

 var highlight = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(v1497_shp, {
                hover: true,
                highlightOnly: true,
                renderIntent: "temporary",
                eventListeners: {
                    beforefeaturehighlighted: info ,
                    featurehighlighted: info ,
                    featureunhighlighted: info 
                }
            });

map.addControl(highlight);
highlight.activate();
```

working examples [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/highlight-feature.html)...

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 1):

Use a SelectFeature control with hover and higlightOnly

```
var select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(v1497_shp, { highlightOnly: true, hover: true });
map.addControl(select);
select.activate();
select.events.register("featurehighlighted",this,function(e){console.log("hover ",e);});
```